# How to parse a single value out of a JSON or CSV string in Microsoft Excel? Or Google Sheets?

Tags: json, excel, vba, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I will have hundreds of cells which will use a webservice call to obtain stock data.  However, the data is only returned in JSON or CSV format.  Using one example, how can I obtain only the "uHigh" value from each dynamic JSON or CSV string, given the example below and knowing that the length of the number value could be different each time?

```
[{"date":"2020-01-22","uClose":1485.95,"uOpen":1491,"uHigh":1503.21,"uLow":1484.93,"uVolume":1610846,"close":1485.95,"open":1491,"high":1503.21,"low":1484.93,"volume":1610846,"change":1.55,"changePercent":0.1044,"label":"Jan 22","changeOverTime":0.001044}]
```

or I can parse CSV such as

```
"date,uClose,uOpen,uHigh,uLow,uVolume,close,open,high,low,volume,change,changePercent,label,changeOverTime,symbol
2020-01-22,1485.95,1491,1503.21,1484.93,1610846,1485.95,1491,1503.21,1484.93,1610846,1.55,0.1044,Jan 22,0.001044,GOOG"
```

Excel offers a FILTERXML method but not one for JSON or CSV to my knowledge, so what can I put in my "=something-here" cell value to parse out just the uHigh value?

I will use Google Sheets if that helps.

Comment: Are you using Sheets or Excel?  You've got an `excel-vba` tag and it would be simple to parse the JSON with a JSON parser.  Then your line would be something like `myuHigh =JSON(1)("uHigh")`  But VBA does not work in Sheets

Answer (score 10):

### For Google Sheets

If you want to extract from JSON **in Google Sheets**, you can use `REGEXEXTRACT` like this:

- Put JSON in `A1`
- Put the key you want to lookup in `B1`
- Put this formula in `C1`: `=REGEXEXTRACT(A1, """" & B1 & """ *: *(.*?),")`

You can test it out by changing the lookup key in `B1`.

[image]

If you want to extract from CSV, you can use this:

- Put CSV in `A1`
- Put the key you want to lookup in `B1`
- Put this formula in `C1`: `=VLOOKUP(B1, TRANSPOSE(ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(A1, char(10))), ","))), 2, FALSE)`

You can test it out by changing the lookup key in `B1`.

**Disclaimer**: Both of these will only work if the JSON/CSV are valid/standard formats. A few things to watch out for:

- The JSON one will fail if the value is quoted and has a comma. For example: `{"key" : "value, value"}`.
- The CSV one will fail if the field separator, comma, is also used in a key/value.

[image]

### For Excel

If you want to extract from JSON **in Excel**, you can use a mix of `SEARCH`, `FIND`, and `MID` like this:

- Put JSON in `A1`
- Put the key you want to lookup in `B1`
- Put this formula in `C1`: `=TRIM(MID(A2,FIND(":", A2, FIND(""""&B2&"""", A2))+1,SEARCH(",",A2,FIND(":", A2, FIND(""""&B2&"""", A2)))-FIND(":", A2, FIND(""""&B2&"""", A2))-1))`

Comment: doesn't work for JSON.          
JSON in A1: `[{"value":"abc","type":"COOL"}]`.         
value in B1: `value`.         
formula in C1: `=REGEXEXTRACT(A1, """" & B1 & """ *: *(.*?),")`.         

          C1 displays `#NAME?` and when I click on the warning, it says `Invalid Name Error`

Comment: what customizations do you need to do to Excel to make it work do I need to add some scripts? because it doesn't work out of the box for me: https://imgur.com/a/ibHV2pz

Comment: The code above is for Google Sheets. I’m not sure how to do it in Excel.

Comment: ah got it. might be worth mentioning this in your answer too, thanks! :)

Comment: I added something that should work in Excel. It works in my tests.

Comment: EXCEL solution works great, but if it contains just one key, it fails:
`{"action":"breadcrumb"}`
While changing data to this works:
`{"action":"breadcrumb",}`.  

Quick and dirty hack to add "," with SUBSTITUTE:
```=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"}",",}"),FIND(":", SUBSTITUTE(A2,"}",",}"), FIND(""""&B2&"""", SUBSTITUTE(A2,"}",",}")))+1,SEARCH(",",SUBSTITUTE(A2,"}",",}"),FIND(":", SUBSTITUTE(A2,"}",",}"), FIND(""""&B2&"""", SUBSTITUTE(A2,"}",",}"))))-FIND(":", SUBSTITUTE(A2,"}",",}"), FIND(""""&B2&"""", SUBSTITUTE(A2,"}",",}")))-1))```

Comment: Thank you for saving me a lot of work. This works well with Excel.

Comment: Is there a formula for doing this extraction for multiple objects in the array, with the same key?

Comment: @DannyDainton In Google or Excel? Post a new question in SO with details/examples.

Answer (score 5):

Extract value after wording "uHigh"

Put `JSON format` type data in `A2`

In `B2`, enter formula :

```
=LOOKUP(9^9,0+MID(A2,SEARCH("uHigh",A2)+7,ROW($1:$99)))
```

[image]

Comment: I think you meant put `JSON format` type data in `A2` -- your `B2` function references `A2` not `A1`.

Answer (score 0):

I've learned one can use Split on a CSV string and then pull the needed item out of the resulting string array by number.  This has been functionalized by another person as seen here:

[find the nth item in a comma separated list](https://www.howtoexcel.org/vba/how-to-find-the-nth-item-in-a-comma-separated-list/)

Of course, it would still be nice to do it in one simpler call.

Answer (score -1):

DISCLAIMER: you'd need Excel Labs/AFE/some other formula IDE to manipulate the "low-level" functions, and the solutions provided use spill arrays.

Solution:

1. Add the Excel Labs add-in,
2. Import [this gist](https://gist.github.com/km594/9cf67702638ee320a1a1e82746c67873) using the add-in, then
3. Add the following function to a cell:

```
=XLOOKUP(
  key,
  module.getJSONKeys(JSONVal),
  module.getJSONValues(JSONVal)
)
```

`key`: your key, no quotes required
`JSONVal`: your JSON value, no quotes required

Example:

```
//Add in cells
A1: {"key": "this is a value", "key2": "another value"}
A2: key
A3: =XLOOKUP(
  key,
  module.getJSONKeys(JSONVal),
  module.getJSONValues(JSONVal)
) // returns: this is a value
```

Notes:

- won't handle JSON arrays, only objects
- does not (yet) extract nested objects
- can handle quotes and commas in the JSON string
- there are a bunch more use/edge-cases that I haven't implemented/thought of